# PowerShell Sort by 2nd Index

Tags: regex, powershell, sorting, match, sort-object

I'm trying to sort servers by the 2nd index of the name.
The server names are taken from file paths where they are the BaseName of the file.
I know that Select-Object has the parameter -Index, but I don't think that will work.
I am assuming that the best approach is with a PowerShell RegEx like "(?:^a-z))". This returns an unsorted list and I'm still googling around for a pattern that will sort by the 2nd Index.

**Example of the Intended Output**

- Group the servers by name CC or DD

```
Server        
------        
ABCCWS01
CDCCWS01
ABDDWS01
CDDDWS01
```

**Current Output**

- Sorts alphabetically by -Property name

```
$servers = Get-Item -Path
C:\ABDDWS01.ServerData, 
C:\ABCCWS01.ServerData, 
C:\CDCCWS01.ServerData, 
C:\CDDDWS01.ServerData | Group BaseName -AsHashtable

foreach($computer in $servers.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property name)
{ ...DoSomething... }

Server        
------        
ABCCWS01
ABDDWS01
CDCCWS01
CDDDWS01
```

Then I tried to implement a PowerShell RegEx. But I'm stuck on how to properly use this to sort by the 2nd index. This example has no affect and returns the list unsorted. I've tried subbing in different patterns at the end "(?:^a-z))". So far my attempts either return the list unsorted or just a segment of the list.
I've googled around and tried many different things. If someone else wants to help puzzle this out, it is much appreciated.

```
Sort-Object -Property @{Expression={[RegEx]::Match($_.basename, "(?:^a-z))")}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sort-Object` works by "ranking" each input according to the resulting value of calculating one or more *property expressions* against each input item - in your existing example, based on the the value of the `name` property.

As you've already found, property expressions doesn't *have to* be the value of any existing property though - they can be made up of anything - just pass a script block in place of the property name:

```
... |Sort-Object -Property {$_.name[1]}
```

The reason it doesn't work in your example is that the expression `[RegEx]::Match($_.basename, "(?:^a-z))")` returns a `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]` object - and those can't be meaningfully compared to one another.

If you change the expression to resolve to a string instead (the matched value for example), it'll work:

```bsh
... |Sort-Object -Property @{Expression={[RegEx]::Match($_.basename, "(?:^a-z))").Value}}
# or
... |Sort-Object -Property {[RegEx]::Match($_.basename, "(?:^a-z))").Value}
```

Comment: Cool that works, kinda. Through the many trials, I did stumble on something like your examples, but I guess I wasn't actually using them correctly. I used {$_.name[2]} and it sorted by 2nd index. Now they're grouped together like I intended, but not in order within the group. I might be looking for the impossible. Maybe I need to sort it a second time after grouping them? I'll keep playing :) Thank you for your quick response, Mathias!

Comment: @JessicaNations What is the purpose of `Group-Object` call in your original example? The `BaseName` values used in the example are all distinct, so each group would only contain a single file anyway?

Comment: I'm not sure how else to use the ```BaseName``` term without ```Group``` in order to create the ```-asHashTable```

Comment: @JessicaNations But do you need a hashtable? Once you do `$ht = $ht.GetEnumerator() |Sort Name` _it's no longer a hashtable anyway_ - it's just an array of key-value pairs. Feel free to hit me up on twitter/gitter if you need help :)

Comment: @JessicaNations Great! You don't need the `GetEnumerator()` call btw, `$servers` is already an array and `foreach` will iterate over it correctly anyway :)

Comment: I finally understand how to sort the way I needed! I took out `Group BaseName -AsHashtable` And ` | Sort-Object -Property name` And just sorted it directly in the array object. I failed to mention the array object in my original question lol and of course the part I excluded contained the answer! `
[pscustomObject]@{
          Status = $Status
          Server = $Computer.BaseName | sort {$_.name[2]}
          KB = $Patch`

Comment: Thank you so much! It took me awhile. I think I was over complicating it. I appreciate all your quick responses. You give very helpful feedback!

Comment: @JessicaNations That makes a lot more sense now ^_^ Happy to be of help!